# How to represent a network of chemical reactions?

Tags: graph-theory, visualization

I am trying to figure out a suitable representation for given set of chemical reactions, which happen over an exhaustive set of chemicals.

The chemicals are $A, B, C, D, E$ and the reactions are given below
$$A + A \rightarrow B$$
$$B + C \rightarrow D$$
$$B + D \rightarrow E$$
$$C + E \rightarrow D$$
$$E + E \rightarrow A$$

It's only obvious to form a matrix representaion of the reactions.
\begin{array}{X}
  & A & B & C & D & E \\
A & B & * & * & * & * \\
B & - & * & D & E & * \\
C & - & - & * & * & D \\
D & - & - & - & * & * \\
E & - & - & - & - & A \\
\end{array}
where $*$ means no product forms

---

I tried to label elements with unique integer IDs, so that the product (if any) can be treated as the weight of the edge, but I failed to incorporate this new property into a visualisation of the matrix.

Can any one tell me what form of graphs can be used to represent such data, where combinaiton of two nodes gives rise to another?

Comment: Perhaps add a "dummy" state $ Z $ and treat $ A+A \rightarrow B"$ as an edge from (A, A) to (B, Z)?

Comment: Use the language of Petri nets.

Comment: [Here](http://reaction-networks.net/wiki/Reaction_graph) is one way to do this. See also [here](http://reaction-networks.net/wiki/Stoichiometry) for the stoichiometric matrix you wrote down.

Answer (score 1):

For a matrix representation, you example seems to most naturally work as a 3D matrix, with the dimensions representing the first reactant, second reactant and product, and the value representing the yield, speed or some other property.

An alternative method might be to have a bipartite directed graph, with reactants/products in one part and the reactions themselves as nodes in the other part:

[image]

This might also work well as a 2D matrix, using a sentinel value of some sort to denote inputs and a yield or other value for the outputs.